# Reading XML with default namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, axapta

Consider this job which work:

```
static void XMLTest(Args _args)
{
    str xml = @'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <tests xmlns="abc">
           <test>
               <testnumber><id>1</id></testnumber>
               <testname>bla bla</testname>
           </test>
       </tests>
   ';
   XMlDocument doc = XMLDocument::newXML(xml);
   XMLNodeList tests = doc.selectNodes('//tests/test');
   XMLNode node;
   for (node = tests.nextNode(); node; node = tests.nextNode())
   {
       info(node.selectSingleNode('testnumber/id').text());
       info(node.selectSingleNode('testname').text());
   }
}
```

It outputs "1" and "bla bla" as expected.

Now change the second line of the xml from:

```
<tests>
```

to:

```
<tests xmlns="xyz">
```

Now it fails to read anything.

How to read XML with a default namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it the strict way via an instance of [XMLNamespaceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) like so

```
static void XMLTest(Args _args)
{
    str xml = @'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <tests xmlns="abc">
           <test>
               <testnumber><id>1</id></testnumber>
               <testname>bla bla</testname>
           </test>
       </tests>
   ';
   XMlDocument doc = XMLDocument::newXML(xml);
   XMLNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XMLNamespaceManager(new XmlNameTable());
   XMLNodeList tests;
   XMLNode node;
   ;

   nsMgr.addNamespace('x', 'abc');
   tests = doc.selectNodes("//x:tests/x:test", nsMgr);

   for (node = tests.nextNode(); node; node = tests.nextNode())
   {
       info(node.selectSingleNode('x:testnumber/x:id', nsMgr).text());
       info(node.selectSingleNode('x:testname', nsMgr).text());
   }
}
```

If for sure no naming conflicts will occur, you may want to ignore the namespace and match the nodes via [local-name()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256070(v=vs.120).aspx)  like so

```
static void XMLTest2(Args _args)
{
    str xml = @'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <tests xmlns="abc">
           <test>
               <testnumber><id>1</id></testnumber>
               <testname>bla bla</testname>
           </test>
       </tests>
   ';
   XMlDocument doc = XMLDocument::newXML(xml);
   XMLNodeList tests = doc.selectNodes("//*[local-name()='tests']/*[local-name()='test']");
   XMLNode node;
   for (node = tests.nextNode(); node; node = tests.nextNode())
   {
       info(node.selectSingleNode("*[local-name()='testnumber']/*[local-name()='id']").text());
       info(node.selectSingleNode("*[local-name()='testname']").text());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, blank the `xmlns` attribute of the root:

```
static void XMLTest(Args _args)
{
    str xml = @'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <tests xmlns="abc">
           <test>
               <testnumber><id>1</id></testnumber>
               <testname>bla bla</testname>
           </test>
       </tests>
   ';
   XMlDocument doc = XMLDocument::newXML(xml);
   XMLNodeList tests;
   XMLNode node;
   ;
   doc.root().attributes().getNamedItem('xmlns').value(''); // Go away xmlns
   doc = XMLDocument::newXML(doc.xml());                    // Now reread all again
   tests = doc.selectNodes("//tests/x:test", nsMgr);   
   for (node = tests.nextNode(); node; node = tests.nextNode())
   {
       info(node.selectSingleNode('testnumber/id').text());
       info(node.selectSingleNode('testname'.text());
   }
}
```

This requires reparsing the XML with `doc = XMLDocument::newXML(doc.xml())`. If the XML is large go for @DAXaholic's first solution.